# values in cocos2d deleted between functions

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

this subject is similar to another i wrote BUT **is different** .
strange things happen to me lately with cocos,things are just deleted .

i have a NSString value in cocos2d class, that is not nil inside animation function.
but when animation is done ,and **she calls** another function, it becomes null in that function.

```
-(void)animation
{   
    // animation loops .....
    //......
    CCAnimate *Action = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:dollAnimation];
    //calling finish animation here :
    id call=[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(finishAnimation)]; 
    id sequence=[CCSequence actions:Action,[CCHide action],call,nil];
    [dollSprite runAction:sequence];
    basic_pic=[rowInDataBase objectAtIndex:1] ;
    NSLog(@"%@",basic_pic); 
    // here basic_pic has a good value!
}


//when animation is done(3sec) it calls this :  
    -(void)finishAnimation
    {
       NSLog(@"%@",basic_pic);    // null ! ! !
       NSLog(@"%@",rowInDataBase);    // null ! ! !


    }
```

how is that happen ???
basic_pic is NSString with no properties now. 
i have to say that basic_pic gets his value frin array one function before animation, and when animation is being called,it still there,but next call to finish function,its gone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you `retain` your `basic_pic` and `rowInDataBase`? If not, they were likely auto-released objects which got released when the current UIKit event completed.

Comment: with property ? how exactly ? i have discover somthing else now ! when i do NSLog(@"%@",basic_pic);  in the finishAnimation function, i get the value! BUT when i do NSLog(@"%s",basic_pic); i get garbage . and when i do : b_pic=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:basic_pic]; its crashes even if it has a value.  whats happen here ?

Comment: anyone ????? i think there is some kind of a HUGE bug in this cocos !! i am loosing it ! what is that ?????? i can see there is a value in the string , and when i do b_pic=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:basic_pic]; its crashes !! it has to do with the fact that same sprite was there before and i removed it with :  [b_pic.parent removeChild:b_pic cleanup:YES];  ???? i can see that sometimes even if i do b_pic=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"regular.png"]; its crashes also! what the f** ?!?!

Comment: What is the value of basic_pic?

Answer (score 0):

solved.

When you want to replace sprites pictures in cocos2d, you better do it like that :

```
CCTexture2D *texmex = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:basic_pic]];
    [b_pic setTexture: texmex];
    [texmex release];
```

and not like that :

```
b_pic=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:basic_pic];
    b_pic.position=ccp(160,175);
    [self addChild:b_pic];
```

because it then crashes because of a memory leaks.
thats worked for me ,and according to cocos documantation, thats how you do that .